# fprintf: writing a cell array to a text file

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array of strings called `myarray`, containing `n` elements. I want to write the array to a text file called `myfile.txt`. I want every line in the text file to correspond to one element in the cell.

When I try the following:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt', 'w');
for i=1:n
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', myarray{i});
end
```

However, this outputs a file without any carriage returns after each element. When I open it in Notepad in Windows, I see just a list of characters which is from the strings in `myarray` concatenated together. However, I want each string to be on its own line.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

With NotePad you might want to use '\r\n' instead of '\n'. Hence:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt', 'w');
for i=1:n
    fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n', myarray{i});
end
```

I can't test it right now though. Take a look at this:

Taken from the Matlab help:

> Some Windows® text editors, including Microsoft® Notepad, require a
>   newline character sequence of '\r\n' instead of '\n'. However, '\n' is
>   sufficient for Microsoft Word or WordPad

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/write-to-delimited-data-files.html#br2ypq2-1

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

- Stop using stupid software, use any other text editor and you will see the new line
- Use [carriage return and line feed](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)